# Cannot start embedded Youtube video by tapping the play button using UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I have a Youtube video embedded into UIWebView on iOS and it has worked correctly so far. The video "poster frame" is displayed and there's the normal red Play button on top of it. Tapping on the play button does nothing but tapping anywhere *outside* the play button starts the video. I first thought this is a problem related to iOS 8 but the same problem happens on iOS 7 (simulator) also. This is really annoying since our users naturally will tap on the play button and it does nothing.

Does anyone know if Youtube has changed something that might be causing this?

Here's the code I'm using for displaying the video within the app:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@", videoId];
NSMutableString* html = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] autorelease];
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendFormat:@"<iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='%0.0f' height='%0.0f' src='%@' frameborder='0'></iframe>", frame.size.width, frame.size.height, urlString];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

NSLog(@"Opening HTML: %@", html);
videoView2 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView2 setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
[videoView2 loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
...
```

Comment: Just a heads up this is also happening with a standard Youtube embed code. I've just had a client call up with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this problem and it seems as if there is a work-around involving the "controls" YouTube player parameter. If you set "controls=0" (the default is "controls=1"), the red play button is clickable. I don't really like this solution since it obviously hides the controls, but it does allow the red play button to be clicked.